# auto text to columns multiple csv using python

Tags: python, csv

I have a lot of csv with a # delimiter and I want to apply "text to columns" for all of them using python.

For example, I have a file "filename.csv" which looks like
1#2#3#4

And I want to rewrite it in the same file so it'd look like this:
1 2 3 4
but each number in it's own column

My code for now is:

```
import csv
with open('filename.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
            with open('out.csv','w') as csvfileout:
            spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='#', quotechar='#')
            spamwriter=csv.writer(csvfileout,delimiter='#',quotechar=' ')
            for row in spamreader:
                    lines=' '.join(row)
                    csvfileout.write(lines)
```

And my output is just wrong.
Could you please help me what's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change *delimiter*, not quotechar.

And you can "pipe" the input directly to the output, keeping data as rows (you were manually creating the row with `join` which is unnecessary):

```
import csv
with open('filename.csv', 'r') as csvfile, open('out.csv','w') as csvfileout:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='#')
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfileout,delimiter=' ')
    spamwriter.writerows(spamreader)
```

note that some python 2 versions need `wb` for output file, and some python 3 versions need the extra parameter `newline=''` when opening the file for writing.

Both are unnecessary with latest python releases (2 or 3).

Comment: thank you.
but still there's a problem - when I use excel to see this, it's not in separate columns, but just in one cell. Is there any way to handle it?

Comment: Instead of `delimiter=' '`, try `dialect=csv.excel` and no delimiter

Comment: excel opens csv files with ";" or "," properly depending on version, but not space.

Comment: I was trying to use dialect=csv.excel with no delimiter, but I got 1,2,3,4 in one cell.
But a result what I need looks like 
1 2 3 4 each number in it's own cell in excel 1 in cell A, 2 in cell B, 3 in cell C, 4 in cell D etc.

Comment: try `separator=';'` then. No spaces but will openOK in your excel. You have to choose.

Comment: thanks a lot, it actually works with ;, but not space.

Comment: you have to choose: either get a file with space separators (you could use ".txt" extension so notepad would open it) so use semi-colon to open it in excel. But not both (unless you use "data => convert" menu, which takes time).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with linux's `sed` command very easily.

First check if its working like so:

```
sed 's/#/ /g' filename
```

If it's working then you can replace all the `#` with `space` like so:

for single file in current folder

```
sed -i 's/#/ /g' filename
```

for all files in current folder

```
sed -i 's/#/ /g' ./*
```